# Can you require two form fields to match with HTML?

Tags: forms, html

Is there a way to require the entries in two form fields to match using HTML? Or does this still have to be done with JavaScript? For example, if you have two password fields and want to make sure that a user has entered the same data in each field, are there some attributes, or other coding that can be done, to achieve this?

Comment: The problem I have encountered with regex pattern matching in HTML5 is that any special character is matched: password: Cat$
confirm password: Cat@ will produce a match in the field confirmation Though I have my validation script that will not allow submission this provides a false indicator to the user.

Comment: The answer to this question is, no there's no way to do this with HTML. And even if there were a way, server-side validation must always be done.

Answer (score 108):

Not exactly with HTML validation but a little JavaScript can resolve the issue, follow the example below:

```js
function check() {
    var input = document.getElementById('password_confirm');
    if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
        input.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
    } else {
        // input is valid -- reset the error message
        input.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" required="required" type="password" id="password" oninput="check()"/>
</p>

<p>
  <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input name="password_confirm" required="required" type="password" id="password_confirm" oninput="check()"/>
</p>

<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: would this code experience an issue if we: 1. type both passwords the same and then 2. go back to the first password field and change the value there?

Comment: Yes, and if you for example enter 'abc' in the first field, and 'bcd' in the second field, and then change the 'abc' in the first field into 'bcd' passwords are matching, but you will still get the invalid input message.

Comment: The issues mentioned in the above comments can be addressed by: 1) Adding `oninput="check(this)"` to the first password field, and 2) changing `input.value` in the function to `document.getElementById('password_confirm').value`. So it becomes `if (document.getElementById('password_confirm').value != document.getElementById('password').value)`

Answer (score 36):

You can with regular expressions **Input Patterns** (check [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern))

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Must have at least 6 characters' : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.password_two.pattern = this.value;" placeholder="Password" required>

<input id="password_two" name="password_two" type="password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');" placeholder="Verify Password" required>
```

Comment: While this works, it's still a bad answer for two reasons: you claim this is an html-only solution, which it isn't, and you don't explain how it works.

Comment: That's probably true. Yet while it is a bad answer, it's a neat solution.
When a value is entered into the first field, it does the password pattern check defined for that input. If doesn't fit your pw pattern it displays a message. If it does match your required pattern, it change the required pattern for the second pw field to be the value the user has entered. If the user enters something in the second field, it must be the value from the first field or the error message is displayed. Pretty nice. I'm giving some thought as to whether this poses any security issues. I don't think it does...

Comment: The trick here is "form.password_two.pattern = this.value", which will break with special characters that have special meaning in regexps

Comment: @wvdz never said it is pure HTML, but added the browser compatibility link for clarity

Comment: @FranciscoToméCosta The question asks for an html-only solution, therefore any answer implicitly claims to be html-only, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: I believe, `pattern` attribute should be omitted for the `password_two` field. As currently, if you type a password, which is shorter than 6 characters into `password_two` field, while leaving `password` empty — it'll show `Please enter the same Password as above` validation message. What might be more confusing: same thing happens if you put in both fields exact same password, that is shorter than 6 characters.

Comment: This solution does not directly check the value of both the password fields for value equality.

Comment: @dequis This can be avoided by escaping all the JS regexp special characters, so `form.password_two.pattern = this.value.split('').map(c => ["\\", ".", "+", "*", "?","[", "^", "]", "$", "(",")", "{", "}", "=", "!","<", ">", "|", ":", "-"].includes(c) ? '\\' + c : c).join('')`

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution with minimal javascript is to use the html attribute pattern (supported by *most* modern browsers). This works by setting the pattern of the second field to the value of the first field.

Unfortunately, you also need to escape the regex, for which no standard function exists.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" oninput="form.confirm.pattern = escapeRegExp(this.value)">
    <input name="confirm" pattern="" title="Fields must match" required>
</form>
<script>
    function escapeRegExp(str) {
      return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I was able to put the function directly into the handler, but I had to put an ID on the confirm: `<input type="password" name="password" oninput="document.getElementById('confirm').pattern = this.value.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&')" required><input type="password" id="confirm" name="confirm" pattern="" title="Fields must match" required>` Not readable like yours, but avoids the separate script/function.

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript will be required, but the amount of code can be kept to a minimum by using an intermediary `<output>` element and an `oninput` form handler to perform the comparison (patterns and validation could augment this solution, but aren't shown here for sake of simplicity):

```
<form oninput="result.value=!!p2.value&&(p1.value==p2.value)?'Match!':'Nope!'">
  <input type="password" name="p1" value="" required />
  <input type="password" name="p2" value="" required />
  <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

Not only HTML but a bit of JavaScript

HTML

```
<form class="pure-form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Confirm password with HTML5</legend>

        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" required>

        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Confirm</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password")
      , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");
    
function validatePassword(){
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity( password.value != 
    confirm_password.value ? "Passwords Don't Match" : '');
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/diegoleme/pen/surIK)

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in other answers, there is no pure HTML way to do this.

If you are already using **JQuery**, then this should do what you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ourForm').submit(function(e){
      var form = this;
      e.preventDefault();
      // Check Passwords are the same
      if( $('#pass1').val()==$('#pass2').val() ) {
          // Submit Form
          alert('Passwords Match, submitting form');
          form.submit();
      } else {
          // Complain bitterly
          alert('Password Mismatch');
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ourForm">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pass1" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pass2" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only with pure html as far as I know, however if you use React for example you could solve it with very little js and html5 together:

```
function MyComp() {
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');

    return (
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Email<br />
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        required
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />      
                </label>
            </div>      
            <div>
                <label>
                    Repeat email<br />
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        required
                        pattern={email /* regular expression just match email value */}
                        title="Emails must match"
                    />      
                </label>
            </div>
            <button>
                Send/Verify
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}
export default MyComp;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }}
          type="password" id='password' name="password" required minLength={3} maxLength={255} />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input
          title='Passwords should be match'
          pattern={`${password}`}
          value={confirmPassword}
          onChange={(e) => { setConfirmPassword(e.target.value) }}
          type="password" id='confirmPassword' name="confirmPassword" required minLength={3} maxLength={255} />
      </div>
```