# HTML validation and field comparison

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Is there currently any way to make a comparison check whether two fields match in HTML validation? Or would you have to write your own JavaScript to do it?

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142527/can-you-require-two-form-fields-to-match-with-html5

Answer (score 2):

That sort of check cannot be done using HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly with HTML5 validation but a little JavaScript can resolve the issue, following is  a general example regarding your question:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Your_Action_Page.php">
<p>Password:</p>
<input name="password" required="required" type="password" id="password" />
<p>Confirm Password:
</p>
<input name="password_confirm" required="required" type="password" id="password_confirm" oninput="check(this)"  />
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function check(input) {
if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
input.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
} else {
// input is valid -- reset the error message
input.setCustomValidity('');
}
}
</script>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```