# html 5 validation of password and confirm password

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How to do validation of password and confirm password in registration form with html 5?? I know how to do with java script and jquery. but i am new to html5 so want to do with it.

```
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id='password1' required>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" id="password2" required>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142527/can-you-require-two-form-fields-to-match-with-html5

Comment: I really don't think you can do this with only HTML5. HTML5 does enable some validation, even pattern matching, but I don't think it can compare two fields. I'm pretty sure you'd need some javascript to compare the two values.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Must have at least 6 characters' : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.password_two.pattern = this.value;" placeholder="Password" required>

<input id="password_two" name="password_two" type="password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');" placeholder="Verify Password" required>
```

Comment: Useful, but this uses JavaScript.