# Prevent form input from being deleted after page is submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where the user inputs his information. Everything works. However, when i pop up a warning message such as 'Password dont match' all fields become clear and the user has to input everything again.

I do not want any fields to be cleared. How do i fix this ?

I have added the normal php code, the html code and the boostrapmodal in the bottom. I hope its clear now

```html
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>KFH Careers Portal</title>

        <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
        <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
        <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body class="bg-dark">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="card card-register mx-auto mt-5">
                <div class="card-header">Register an Account</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" class = "form-horizontal " role = "form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" minlength="3" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastname" minlength="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="required">
                                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" minlength="5" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required="required">
                                <label for="username">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" minlength="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <input type="number" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" minlength="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required">
                                <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" minlength="5" name="passone" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                                        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" minlength="5" name="passtwo" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" required="required">
                                        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="login.html">Register</a>-->
                        <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

                    </form>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a class="d-block small mt-3" href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                        <a class="d-block small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
        <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>


<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

        
        if($_POST['passone'] == $_POST['passtwo'])
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#logoutModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>


<?php
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        

    }

?>

  <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Username or Password is incorrect.</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Ok</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Clearly it cannot be achieved in pure html. But with JavaScript it will be possible.

Comment: How do you check if "password not match"?

Comment: @Roy check if the two inputs match each other, if they dont a model pop up message will appear and then the page is reset.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion could you provide a link?

Comment: So, where's your javascript? where's the comparation between password? Can you add it?

Comment: You can use php or JavaScript to do it

Comment: @Roy i have added my entire code now please check it

Comment: @AdnanToky i am using PHP, i have added my entire code now please check it and tell me how i can solve this issue using PHP

Comment: You need to use `ajax` if you want to NOT reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['text_input']) && $_POST['text_input']!=""){
    $_SESSION['text_input'] = $_POST['text_input'];
    //handle other form stuff here
}
?>

<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="text_input" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['text_input']) && $_SESSION['text_input']!=""){echo " value='".$_SESSION['text_input']."'";} ?> >
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I save the posted value as a session variable in PHP and if it is set use it as the value.

Obviously this is just an example with one input but you can just expand the same logic for the other inputs.

I also sometimes put an else statement within the input, for example:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['value']) && $_SESSION['value']!=""){
    echo " value='".$_SESSION['value']."'";
}else{
    echo " placeholder='enter a value'";
}
```

Comment: This worked! i just removed the value= from the echo and it worked fine

Comment: @ahmed I'd say you've made a mistake somewhere, the value would be needed for this??

Comment: value="<?php
                                if (isset($_SESSION['regnum']) && $_SESSION['regnum'] != "") {
                                    echo "" . $_SESSION['regnum'] . "";
                                }
                                ?>"

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `type = 'submit'` will refresh the form by default. Just replace the value of type attribute on the submit button sa `type = 'button'` and in your JS attach a click listener to handle submit manually on the click of the said button.

```js
// get reference of the submit button from the DOM
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

// attach an click eventlistener on the submit button 
submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // handle your submit here 
  // extra validation, data modifications, form POST etc
  console.log('form submitted')
})
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class = "form-horizontal " role = "form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" minlength="3" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastname" minlength="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="required">
                                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" minlength="5" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required="required">
                                <label for="username">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" minlength="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <input type="number" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" minlength="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required">
                                <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" minlength="5" name="passone" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                                        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-label-group">
                                        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" minlength="5" name="passtwo" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" required="required">
                                        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="login.html">Register</a>-->
                        <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the link that uses the JavaScript to test the password and confirm password [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142527/can-you-require-two-form-fields-to-match-with-html5)

But in your case, the submit button must not be a type submit.
Like this

```
<form action="" method="post" class = "form-horizontal "  role = "form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" minlength="3" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                    <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastname" minlength="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="required">
                    <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" minlength="5" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required="required">
            <label for="username">User Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" minlength="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="number" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" minlength="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required">
            <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" minlength="5" name="passone" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" minlength="5" name="passtwo" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" required="required">
                    <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="login.html">Register</a>-->
    <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="validatepass();" type="button" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-form-submit" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

</form>
<script>
function validatepass(){
var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
var confirm = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;
    if(pass == confirm){
        document.getElementById("btn-form-submit").click();

    }else{
        alert("Password not match!");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code sample shows how to prevent input from being deleted. When we submit the form, it stores the data in separate variables and pass those data to the user as input value.

```
<?php
    $name = $email = $pasd = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $pass; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Do not use this process for password or other sensitive data.**
Use your own validation method to handle errors.