# Using php to set value of html input field

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to set the value of an input text field with php, but it does not seem to work.
There are many similar Questions where the answer was something like this:

```
<?php $value = "Show This!" ?>
<form>
<input type="text" name="testname" value="<?php echo $value;?>" >
</form>
```

But this will print the whole *<?php...* stuff in the text field like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFZva.png).

For clarification:. I am expecting to see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMQvr.png).

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I also tried several variants with/without string symbols, also the shorthand variant `<input type="text" value="<?=$value?>">`  and even something without a php variable:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="testname" value="<?php echo 'Show this please';?>" >
</form>
```

Comment: Is your PHP server running? Does the file have the .php extension?

Comment: Your code is totaly not the probleme. Check the server. Check the file extension. Create a index.php and just write `<?php phpinfo();` and run it for see your php informations , if php is running

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP code is not being executed code shows in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-code-shows-in-browser)

Comment: @WaisKamal I am using the code in a Wordpress site which probably is an .html file, so that is indeed the problem.
What I initially inteded to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55394275)

Guess I will have to try out some javascript solutions then...

Comment: Yes it can be done with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks correct, you just need to run it as PHP instead of HTML