# How can I verify form passwords match using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, passwords

I have a basic html form with password and verify password fields. I want to only allow users to continue if passwords match. If passwords do not match, I want there to be a notification to the user.

I think that what I currently have is close, but the JS still doesn't appear to do anything.

HTML

```
<form class="ajax-form" id="pwreset" method="post" onsubmit="return verifyPassword()" action="/set-password">
        <div id="userinput">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/><br/>
            <label for="new_password">Password</label>
            <input type="Password" id="new_password" name="new_password"/><br/>
            <label for="verifyPassword">Verify Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="verifyPassword" name="verifyPassword"/><br/>
            <input type="hidden" id="uuid" name="uuid" value="{{uuid}}"/>
      <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></p>
        </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
function verifyPassword() {
  let pass1 = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
  let pass2 = document.getElementById("verifyPassword").value;
    let match = true;
  if (pass1 != pass2) {
    //alert("Passwords Do not match");
    document.getElementById("new_password").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("verifyPassword").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
    match = false;
  }
  else {
    alert("Passwords match.");
  }
  return match;
}
```

Comment: If I can download your page then the browser "view source" function [CTRL]+[U] will show me your plaintext password in your JS code. Think again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you require two form fields to match with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142527/can-you-require-two-form-fields-to-match-with-html5)

Comment: @Dougie: The user entering a value into the "verify password" field also entered the value into the "password" field.  They already know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues that can come from putting the javascript call in the HTML.

In your case, the function was probably defined after the HTML, so the element didn't have access to it.

You can use this instead:

```js
function verifyPassword() {
  let pass1 = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
  let pass2 = document.getElementById("verifyPassword").value;
  let match = true;
  if (pass1 != pass2) {
    //alert("Passwords Do not match");
    document.getElementById("new_password").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("verifyPassword").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
    match = false;
  }
  else {
    alert("Passwords match.");
  }
  return match;
}

document.getElementById('pwreset').onsubmit = verifyPassword;
```

```html
<form class="ajax-form" id="pwreset" method="post" action="/set-password">
  <div id="userinput">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br/>
    <label for="new_password">Password</label>
    <input type="Password" id="new_password" name="new_password" /><br/>
    <label for="verifyPassword">Verify Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="verifyPassword" name="verifyPassword" /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" id="uuid" name="uuid" value="{{uuid}}" />
    <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. I created a passwordGroup constructor to centralize the information. This way it's easier to write tests also.

```js
var form = document.forms[0];
var pass1 = form.querySelector('[data-password]');
var pass2 = form.querySelector('[data-password-confirmation]');
var submitButton = form.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

// PasswordGroup constructor
var PasswordGroup = function () {
  this.password = '';
  this.passwordConfirmation = '';
};

// method to update the passwords values
PasswordGroup.prototype.setValues = function(data) {
  this.password = data.password;
  this.passwordConfirmation = data.passwordConfirmation;
};

// method to check the password's equality
PasswordGroup.prototype.match = function() {
  return !!(this.password 
  && this.passwordConfirmation 
  && this.password === this.passwordConfirmation);
};

/*
* Enable/disable the submit button if passwords do not match
*/
function validateSubmit() {
  if(passwordGroup.match()) {
    submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

// passwordGroup instance
var passwordGroup = new PasswordGroup();

// objecto to store the current values
var passwordsValues = {
  password: '',
  passwordConfirmation: '',
};

// event triggered after enter a new value in the password's field
var onPasswordChange = function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var targetValue = target.value;
  
  if(target.dataset.hasOwnProperty('password')) {
    passwordsValues.password = targetValue;
  } else if (target.dataset.hasOwnProperty('passwordConfirmation')) {
    passwordsValues.passwordConfirmation = targetValue;
  }

  passwordGroup.setValues(passwordsValues);
  validateSubmit();
};

// event attribution
pass1.onkeyup = onPasswordChange;
pass2.onkeyup = onPasswordChange;
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" name='account'>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" /> 
  <input type="password" data-password placeholder="password"/>
  <input type="password" data-password-confirmation placeholder="repeat password"/>
  <button type="submit" disabled="disabled">Enviar</button>
</form>

<p data-message></p>
```